# How to resolve: Error Loading Native Library: grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll, while using a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, grpc-c#

I have integrated Firebase Firestore in my WinForm Application. After I install my application through a Visual Studio Installer project, and once the routine gets called for fetching data from the Firestore, I get this error saying **Error Loading Native Library: grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll**. Here is the exception text:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error loading native library. Not
> found in any of the possible locations: C:\Program Files (x86)\Default
> Company
> Name\desktopModuleForFypInstaller\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Default Company
> Name\desktopModuleForFypInstaller\runtimes/win-x86/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll,C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Default Company
> Name\desktopModuleForFypInstaller../..\runtimes/win-x86/native\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
> at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary.FirstValidLibraryPath(String[]
> libraryPathAlternatives)    at
> Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[]
> libraryPathAlternatives)    at
> Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethodsUsingExplicitLoad()
> at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()    at
> Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()    at
> Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()    at
> Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()    at
> Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()    at
> Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()    at
> Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor(String target, ChannelCredentials credentials,
> IEnumerable`1 options)    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcCore.GrpcCoreAdapter.CreateChannelImpl(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcAdapter.CreateChannel(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)    at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateChannel(String endpoint,
> ChannelCredentials credentials)    at
> Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateCallInvoker()    at
> Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl()    at
> Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.Build()    at
> Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDbBuilder.Build()    at
> Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb.Create(String projectId,
> FirestoreClient client)    at FYP_Desktop.DBConnection..ctor()    at
> FYP_Desktop.CashierDashboard.d__1.MoveNext()